# How to memoize array of selectors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reselect

Example code:

```
const menu = [
  {type: "home", visSelector: someSelector},
  {type: "accounts", visSelector: anotherSelector}
]

const filterMenuItems = (state, menu) =>
  menu.filter(i => i.visSelector(state))

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  menuItems: filterMenuItems(state, menu)
}
```

What is **the right way** to memoize filterMenuItems?

visSelector are already memoized. Unfortunately, result of this filtration rerender component every time.

Comment: It has to, as `visSelector` makes its decision based on the whole state, which changes at every rerender

Comment: Yep, i know. But how to handle such a case nicely?

Answer (score 1):

Provided the items are pure component, they won't *all* be re-rendered every time. Only the ones you're adding back after having previously removed them.

For instance, here we start out with all four children shown. If you uncheck one of the checkboxes, two of the children disappear, but no children are re-rendered. It's only if you add them back that they're re-rendered.

```js
const Child = props => {
  console.log("render", props.name);
  return <div>{props.name}</div>
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.children = [
      <Child key={0} name="zero" />,
      <Child key={1} name="one" />,
      <Child key={2} name="two" />,
      <Child key={3} name="three" />
    ];
    this.state = {
      showOdds: true,
      showEvens: true
    };
  }
  evensClick = event => {
    this.setState({showEvens: event.currentTarget.checked});
  };
  oddsClick = event => {
    this.setState({showOdds: event.currentTarget.checked});
  };
  render() {
    const {showEvens, showOdds, counter} = this.state;
    return <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.evensClick} checked={showEvens} />
          Show evens
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.oddsClick} checked={showOdds} />
          Show odds
        </label>
        <div>
          {this.children.filter((child, index) => index % 2 == 0 ? showEvens : showOdds)}
        </div>
      </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I don't think there's a way to prevent them being re-rendered when being added back.

Alternatively, you could use CSS to manager their *visibility*, which would prevent re-rendering them:

```js
const Child = props => {
  console.log("render", props.name);
  return <div className={props.index % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"}>{props.name}</div>
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.children = [
      <Child index={0} key={0} name="zero" />,
      <Child index={1} key={1} name="one" />,
      <Child index={2} key={2} name="two" />,
      <Child index={3} key={3} name="three" />
    ];
    this.state = {
      showOdds: true,
      showEvens: true
    };
  }
  evensClick = event => {
    this.setState({showEvens: event.currentTarget.checked});
  };
  oddsClick = event => {
    this.setState({showOdds: event.currentTarget.checked});
  };
  render() {
    const {showEvens, showOdds, counter} = this.state;
    const cls = (showEvens ? "" : "hide-evens ") + (showOdds ? "" : "hide-odds");
    return <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.evensClick} checked={showEvens} />
          Show evens
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.oddsClick} checked={showOdds} />
          Show odds
        </label>
        <div className={cls}>
          {this.children}
        </div>
      </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.hide-evens .even {
  display: none;
}
.hide-odds .odd {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good answer, but instead of creating such complex class, we can simply write:

shouldComponentUpdate({menuItems}) {
  return this.props.menuItems.length !== menuItems.length ||
    !this.props.menuItems.every((item, key) => item === menuItems[key])
}

Comment: @ku8ar - That's not at all the same thing at all. That's just not re-rendering the parent component if the menu items haven't changed (which is pretty much the default behavior).

Answer (score 0):

[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array on each call. You might want to try and memoize `filterMenuItems` based on your application requirements.

In the example below `filterMenuItems`, returns a new array only when `state` or `menu` arguments change:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const filterMenuItems = createSelector(
    state => state,
    (state, menu) => menu,
    (state, menu) => menu.filter(i => i.visSelector(state))
);
```

Comment: And make sure you don't recreate `menu` itself every time!  That will also stop it from caching since it'll invalidate the inputs.